# Drupal 7 javascript aggregate

Tags: javascript, optimization, drupal-7, drupal-modules

For javascript aggregation I have used Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation module but when enable option for Aggregate JavaScript files, sites is crashing.

Folks are saying to remove jquery_update module and it will work fine. But i need jquery_update for other modules.

Is there any other module which does the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to optimize js then you can also use below module in Drupal 7.

https://www.drupal.org/project/js_defer

Comment: Thanks for this. But i am not a core drupal developer and dont know what js files are using for each page, so is there any module which can be directly enabled and it will work. By combining javascript, I want to minimize http requests.

Comment: yes I understood. This module will help you.. You Just need to install it and it will minify all js synchronously by itself. you don't need to do anything!

Comment: hi @Shripal, I installed this module & enabled. But no js is optimizated or minified. I have checked performance on gtmerix and still asks for - Minify JavaScript. Is there anything I missed out or configuration?

Comment: also you need to checked the checkbox named as "Aggreagate javascript" on performance page and save it. after that, please clear the cache.. and again check on GTmetrix..